# How to prove that $\ln(n)$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I can prove that a sequence or function converges however I have no idea how to prove that it diverges using the epsilon and delta values.

Comment: Hint: prove that for any $M$ there exists $n$ such that $\ln(n) > M$.

Comment: The standard way is to show that any attempt to show that it converges will fail. There are basically two ways of doing that: One is to go with what lisyarus above says, the other is to assume that there is some limit $L$, then use the definition of convergence to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know some properties of $\ln$?

Comment: Since $e<3$, it follows that $e^M<3^M$ and therefore $M=\ln(e^M)<\ln(3^M)$. This means that if you want $\ln(n)$ to be greater than a given $M$ you can just put $n=3^M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C \in \Bbb R$. Choose $n \ge e^C $. Then we have (note that $\ln$ is increasing)

$$\ln(n) \ge ln(e^C) = C.$$

That means $\ln$ is not bounded and hence it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Render

$\ln(n)=\int_1^n\frac{dx}{x}$

Show, by putting in $u=x/n$, that

$\ln(2n)-\ln(n)=\int_1^2\frac{du}{u}=ln(2)$

Then for instance

$\ln(5)>\ln(4)=\ln(2)+\ln(2)=2\ln(2),$

$\ln(12)>\ln(8)=\ln(2)+\ln(4)=3\ln(2),$

and as $n$ increases without bound the coefficient of $\ln(2)$ does the same.  Compare with proving the divergence of the harmonic series.